# Insertar json en un campo tipo json de MySQL con PHP

Tags: php, mysql, sql, json, insert

Tengo la siguiente tabla en MySQL:

```
CREATE TABLE sec(
   id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
   fecha DATE NOT NULL,
   datos JSON NOT NULL,
   PRIMARY KEY (id)
);
```

Y debo insertar registros sacándolos de un fichero json con PHP.  La prueba la estoy haciendo con un sólo registro:

```
<?php
// Abre el fichero
$json = file_get_contents('p.json');
// Extrae los datos
$obj = json_decode($json,true);
// Conecta con la base
$mysqli = new mysqli("localhost", "USER", "PASS", "DATABASE");
// Hace el insert
$sql="INSERT INTO sec VALUES('2019-01-14', '$obj')";
$result = mysqli_query($mysqli,$sql);
?>
```

Pero no lo hace.
¿Qué estoy haciendo mal?
Desde ya muchas gracias

Comment: Podrías mostrar el contenido del archivo, p.json? Saludos.

Comment: ¿Has intentado imprimir el valor de $json y $obj antes de ingresarlos a la BD? podría ser que tengan un valor vacío y al ingresarlos en la BD como es un campo not null te de un error.

Comment: estas opteniendo un arreglo y no puedse insertarlo todo en un solo campo al menos que le hagas un cast a string y se inserte como texto o hacer un bucle e insertar registro por registro!

Answer (score 1):

Como comenta el usuario Bryro el error es que decodifica el json en un array cuando no es necesario.
La línea:

```
$obj = json_decode($json,true);
```

No es necesaria.